# Capturing all sets of capital letter blocks / groups

Tags: ruby, regex

I am trying to extract all sets of capital letters in the following sample string:

```
"ABCDE: Something ABC DEF GHI others plus JKL MNO and PQR"
```

I am looking for:

```
["ABCDE", "ABC DEF GHI", "JKL MNO", "PQR"]
```

I have the following regex:

```
mystring.scan(/\b[A-Z][A-Z0-9]+\b(?:\s[A-Z][A-Z0-9]+)+/) 
#=> ["ABC DEF GHI", "JKL MNO"]
```

Not so sure what's missing here. Hoping to get some advice.

Comment: Not clear what "capital letter blocks" mean.

Comment: A regex does not do anything by itself. You should show what method you used with it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to replace last `+` with `*` since `+` repeats the previous token one or more times where `*` repeats the previous token zero or more times.

```
> str.scan(/\b[A-Z][A-Z0-9]+\b(?:\s[A-Z][A-Z0-9]+)*/)
=> ["ABCDE", "ABC DEF GHI", "JKL MNO", "PQR"]
```

Comment: The two `\b`s are redundant.

Answer (score 0):

Consider this, it may simplify the regex but may have to do some processing outside.

```
text = "ABCDE: Something ABC DEF GHI others plus JKL MNO and PQR"
text.scan(/\b[A-Z\s]+\b/).map { |s| s.strip }.reject &:empty? # => ["ABCDE", "ABC DEF GHI", "JKL MNO", "PQR"]
```